# SQL inserts a one-row series in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to add 1 record to 2 tables with one query

**Tables blogs**

```
id                    blogs_title        blog_key  blogs_image   created_at   updated_at
INT PRIMARY [AI]      VARCHAR PRIMARY    VARCHAR   VARCHAR       DATE         DATE
```

**Table blog_contetn**

```
id                 blog_key        body 
INT PRIMARY [AI]   VARCHAR PRIMARY  VARCHAR
```

**i thought this way, but it didn't work, by the way i am new to SQL**

```
INSERT INTO blogs(
    blogs_title,
    blogs_key,
    blogs_image,
    created_at,
    updated_at,
    body
)
SELECT
    B.blogs_title,
    B.blogs_key,
    B.blogs_image,
    B.created_at,
    B.updated_at,
    BC.body
FROM
    blogs B
INNER JOIN blog_content BC ON
    B.blogs_key = BC.blog_key
```

****I wish someone could give me some feedback****

Comment: It is not possible. Well, unless you write a stored procedure that does the two inserts and count its invocation as "one query".

Comment: isn't that the same as doing 2 queries?

Comment: Depends from where you're looking. It's one roundtrip between app and DB.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, you need two `insert` statements to insert into two tables.  You *could* define the second update through a trigger, but that seems like unnecessary complication.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `blogs` doesn't have column `body` and `blog_contents` doesn't have `blogs_title`. A trigger won't help here, I think?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `UPDATE`?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`; if it is 2 columns, then why?